# Impact on SEO for scraped news content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, rel-canonical, rss, scraper-sites

I'm making a finance website and apart from our core features, I also want to show the latest news.

These news articles are scraped from RSS feeds (full-article scraping) of some reputed news sources (ex.CNN), but posts also have `rel=canonical` tags to their original source. All links in posts are redirecting to original source, but news will be mostly scraped word-for-word.

Is it going to negatively impact my SEO? Should I consider using `nofollow` in `robots.txt`? I just want to curate news articles for the ease of our users. I really don't want to get any SEO benefits from these articles as our core business is not showing the news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rel=canonical` is a good idea.  That lets search engines know about the original source of the content and should prevent most penalties that could come from syndicating content.

`robots.txt` does not have any `nofollow` directive.   You could `disallow` those URLs in robots.txt.   Doing so would be wise as it would prevent Google from even seeing duplicated content on your site.   Of course, if Google can't see the content, it also won't see the `rel=canonical`, but that would probably be fine.

Instead of `robots.txt` you could consider using a `noindex` meta tag in the page to prevent Google from indexing them.    Google occasionally indexes URLs blocked by robots.txt without ever seeing the content on those pages.   Allowing crawling, but using `noindex` is a sure fire way to prevent the URLs from ever appearing in Google's search index.

The biggest threat to your site from this is from a legal perspective.   Make sure you get proper licenses from the content creators to syndicate their content.   If you are scraping and publishing content without permission, the news sites will not be happy and will try to get your site shut down.  They may file DMCA (Digital Millennium Copyright Act) takedowns with your host or with Google.